# Target Blank PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, target

I have this line and I want to target blank so as to open the link in a new window. I tried adding it but but I get syntax error.

```
  $out .= "\t<li><a href=\"" . $content->getURL() . "\">" . $content . "</a></li>\n";
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: if you are appending `.=` an expression to a variable, then that variable i.e. (`$out`) must be have been declared first

Comment: I tried the following:

 '$out .= "\t<li><a  target="_blank" href=\"" . $content->getURL() . "\">" . $content . "</a></li>\n";'

Comment: Would Javascript work? - like adding a div and then target all links within that div to blank

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of this question. You've tried to add `target="_blank"` while using double-quotes for the variable too. This won't work. You'll have to escape the characters, or use singlequotes. Like this:

```
$out .= "\t<li><a target=\"_blank\"href=\"" . $content->getURL() . "\">" . $content . "</a></li>\n";
```

This will only work if $out is defined, since you're using .= the concatenating assignment operator, which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'm against sticking HTML within PHP variables. I strongly believe in the MVC methodology where you prepare your data and then display it in a template file.

However to help you with your issue you might find it easier to use single quotes when wrapping HTML in a PHP string variable. Firstly make sure your `$out` variable is definitely defined, then do something like this:

```
$out .= '<li><a href="' . $content->getURL() . '" target="_blank">' . $content . '</a></li>';
```

Notice that I don't have to escape the double quotes when wrapping the HTML with a single quote. There are differences between using single quotes and double quotes, more information about that here: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)